# Replace two calls of functions with define

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I want to replace a flow of transforming `QString` to `char*` in Qt4:

```
str.toLatin1().data()
```

to the same in Qt3:

```
str.latin()
```

using some construction as:

```
#define toLatin1().data() latin()
```

Is it really? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you write a function that lets you do `to_latin(str)`?

Comment: @juanchopanza just because at some moment I want to switch to Qt4 and get rid of workarounds

Comment: If you are making Qt4 look like Qt3, how do you intend to remove the work-arounds?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'll remove this `define` and code will simply contain `str.toLatin1().data()` - Qt4 syntax

Comment: There's no good way to do this.  `#define` needs an identifier on the left - you can't have parenthesis and full stops inside it.  You could make substitutions that inject a proxy object whose `.data()` function returns the desired `QByteArray`, but you'd need to introduce an operator between the `QString` and your proxy, and then precedence rules would mean that code such as `str.toLatin1().data().xyz()` would become something like `str.latin() * Helper().data().xyz()` - the problem is the `.xyz()` would be invoked before `operator*` allowed the `Helper` to capture the `QByteArray`.

Comment: @Tony D  Thanks, I think, I shouldn't try to use `define`

Comment: How many of these do you really have? SUrely, the easy way is to just fix them....

Comment: @Mats Petersson many, I wanted by means of a `define` construction to make code switchable between Qt3 and Qt4. Fix won't allow this.

Comment: Write a function and switch inside your function, not all over your code. Change should be isolated. And macros are almost always a bad choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the most maintainable solution would be to introduce a function for it:

```
inline const char* qstringToLatinChar(const QString &str)
{
#if Qt4
  return str.toLatin1().data();
#else
  return str.latin();
#endif
}
```

Such a function can quickly be substituted at existent code sites even with `sed` or the like. It has the added benefit of introducing a meaningful name for the operation.